# link rails and mysql with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to get a basic rails + mysql application running in docker.
my docker compose is as follows:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.12
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

my db builds just fine using `docker-compose up db`, but my web service can't seem to find the db. Trying to compose it all together `docker-compose up` yields the following error:

```
web_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect': 
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)
```

How can i get the containers to link properly?

---

EDIT: the answer was in my database.yml file. As per the accepted answer I had to change the

```
development:
  host: localhost
```

lines in my `database.yml` to

```
development:
  host: db (my container name)
  port: 3306
```

and then additionally update my `docker-compose.yml` db enviroment with the `MYSQL_DATABASE` name from my `database.yml`

Comment: try to telnet from the web container the default port of your mysql

Comment: How does your rails database.yml look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define database settings for your rails application.
Now app tries to connect to local database.

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)

try follows settings:

```
host: db
port: 3306
```